# array name stored in array, pushing to array - not working as expected

Tags: arrays, ruby, push

```
@board = {1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0, 5=>0, 6=>0, 7=>0, 8=>"b", 9=>"r", 10=>"u", 11=>"c", 12=>0, 13=>0, 14=>"d", 15=>"h", 16=>"s", 17=>"l", 18=>0, 19=>0, 20=>"o", 21=>"i", 22=>"l", 23=>"b", 24=>0, 25=>0, 26=>"g", 27=>"t", 28=>"f", 29=>"e", 30=>0, 31=>0, 32=>0, 33=>0, 34=>0, 35=>0, 36=>0}
@words = {"shift"=>[16, 15, 21, 28, 27], "bell"=>[23, 29, 22, 17], "curb"=>[11, 10, 9, 8], "dog"=>[14, 20, 26]}

@col1 = [8, 14, 20, 26]
@col2 = [9, 15, 21, 27]
@col3 = [10, 16, 22, 28]
@col4 = [11, 17, 23, 29]

@rcol1 = Array.new
@rcol2 = Array.new
@rcol3 = Array.new
@rcol4 = Array.new

@cols = [@col1, @col2, @col3, @col4]
@rcols0 = [@rcol1, @rcol2, @rcol3, @rcol4]

out = @words["dog"]

 out.each do |remove|
  @board[remove] = 100
 end

def colclone
  nums = 0
  @rcols0.each do |fixy|
    a = @cols[nums]
    a.each do |stick|
      fixy[nums].push @board[stick]
    end
    nums += 1
  end
end
```

Here's the *actual* code. I tried to simplify but I think I must have left something out.

I am working on a board game. What I want is

```
--> @rcol1 = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

what I am getting is those results in my reference array instead

```
--> @rcols0 = [[0, 1, 2, 3], ...]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to push all elements of the arrays, which are inside the names array to array1?

Comment: It's better to have a working example, rather than `...`, particularly here where it's no more difficult. Just define (sic) `array2 = [5,6,7]` and `names = [array1, array2]`. I see no problem with your code.

Comment: the board game has a 4x4 grid. when you find a word, the letters disappear and the other letters 'fall' to fill in any gaps. Thus, the board has four columns. We're replacing dog in this test. Dog's letters will be replaced by 100. All instances of 100 get removed (by a later and not included method). colclone creates temporary copies of each column, but instead it's wrecking my reference array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong idea, or the wrong vocabulary, about how it works.  `names` does not store the names of the arrays.  `names` stores *a reference to the Array objects*.  It doesn't matter what they're named.

```
array1 = [0, 1, 2]
array2 = [10,20,30]
names = [array1, array2]

# names[1] contains a reference to array2
# So this is the same as array2[2]
puts names[1][2]   # 30
```

Your code works fine.

```
names.each do |update|
  update.push 3
  update.push 4
end

puts array1.inspect # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: OK! I think I have figured out my problem. At one point, I had my @rcol1 coming back nil. Later, I was checking @ rcols0, and seeing it (correctly) returning not the values I put in it, but the values from each array (@ rcol1, etc). I mistook this for the values going to the wrong place. My bad! Coding lesson #3, the problem may not still be where it was a second ago.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems to be working:

```
array1 = [1,2,3]
 => [1, 2, 3] 

array2 = [4,5,6]
 => [4, 5, 6] 

names = [array1, array2]
 => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] 

names.each do |update|
  update.push 8
  update.push 9
end
 => [[1, 2, 3, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6, 8, 9]] 

array1
 => [1, 2, 3, 8, 9] 

array2
 => [4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Answers are easier to read (and can be cut and pasted if desired) without the IRB prompts.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, how do you do that?  I actually would be interested in learning that trick.  All I ever do is `cat ~/.irb_history`.

Comment: Just edit out the messy parts after you paste to the SO answer box and before you post. Now, just click on edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this is what you're looking for:

```
array1 = [0, 1, 2]
array2 = [10, 11, 12]
array3 = [20, 21, 22]

names = [array1, array2, array3]

names.each do |array|
    i = array[array.length-1] + 1
    array.push(i,i+1)
end

p array1
p array2
p array3
p names
```

Output for the above is:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]      #array1
[10, 11, 12 ,13, 14] #array2       
[20, 21, 22, 23, 24] #array3
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]] #names array
```

Modify and/or extend the code to suit your needs.